# Using an Intent in a list onItemClick

Tags: android, listview, click, android-intent

I am on my second activity (Main) like so:

```
Login -> Main -> Vforum
```

I managed to get to the Main activity using an Intent like so in the Login activity:

```
Intent logMeIn = new Intent(this,Main.class);
startActivity(logMeIn);
```

That works fine. My issue right now is going from Main to Vforum.

```
projectList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent launchVforum = new Intent(this, Vforum.class);
        startActivity(launchVforum);
    }
});
```

`projectList` is a `ListView`. Eclipse is saying:

```
The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Vforum>) is undefined
```

and I don't know what to put where `this` is to fix it. I just want to go to my third activity (Vforum).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep. Have had similar issue once. My solution was to do the following (using your example):

-In your Main activity put a private context like so:

```
private Context mCtx;
```

-In your Main activity onCreate() method put this line somewhere:

```
mCtx = this;
```

-When creating the intent use mCtx instead of this:

```
Intent launchVforum = new Intent(mCtx, Vforum.class);
```

Comment: To explain, the problem is that the first parameter needs to be a Context object. You can also try Main.this if you don't want to save the Context

Answer (score 3):

```
projectList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent launchVforum = new Intent(YourActivity.this, Vforum.class);
        startActivity(launchVforum);
    }
});
```